# How to remove a PDF annotation using JavaScript or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, annotations, edit

I found some libraries to add annotations for pdf documents like [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) but I cannot find at the documentation anything about how to remove an annotation from the pdf document.
Is this possible using `pdf-lib` or any other library in the browser or at the server using nodejs?